# Neural Network: validation accuracy constant, training accuracy decreasing

Tags: neural-network, image-segmentation

I have a neural network which does image segmentation. I trained it ~100 epochs. The current effect is that the validation loss is constant (`0.2 +/- 0.03`) and the training accuracy is still decreasing (currently `0.07`), but very slow.

The result of the neural network is quite well.
What does this mean? Is it overfitting? Should i stop the training?

I currently use dropout in the first layer (`50%`). Would it make sense to add dropout to every layer (there are about ~15 layers)? Or should i also add `L2` regularization? Does it make sense to use `L2` and also droput?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use L2 when you use dropout. I think that your dropout at 50% is a little too high. People usually use it around 20% depending on the operations.

Moreover, 100 epochs may not be enough, it depends on the size of your training set and the size of your neural network.

What do you mean by "quite well"? Please quantify it and share an example. The validation and accuracy are just "indicators", their value also depend on the NN and the training set, so 0.2 can be either bad or good depending on your problem.